# line break inside a list item generates space between the lines

Tags: html, css

I want to break line `<br/>` inside a `<li>` 
Like:

- *First line

  second line*
- *Second li*
- *third li*

but when doing so (both labels)- I get a space between them.
margin and padding is 0 but still I get it..
any idea how to get rid of it?
Thanks!

Comment: +1 Hmm, I was going to answer, but I realized I don't know either other than some hacks.  Good question.

Comment: Can you show us your live example? It's hard to tell you what's going on without it :)

Comment: Hi,

You may need to provide your css as the list you are showing is the default functionality of a UL and should be working if you have not altered the css too much.

As Uw Concept said the line height you have applied may be too big and showing more space than is wanted.

Cheers

Comment: I believe the OP is asking about possible margin/padding between the LIs themselves, not the `<br>` issue. Waiting for code.

Comment: seems like the line-height issue as feela suggested. but this is weird since even if the line height is very short, the problem appears. only when auto it's solved. see link for examples: http://mysports-test.co.il/TestPAge.htm

Comment: Even though it's a strange issue, feeela and Uw Concept directed me to the right path. how do I know who was first so I can mark as answer? (both seems like 1 hour ago).Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can alter the `line-height` property in your css. Does that help ?

Comment: Although I have a big problem with this, it seems this is the issue - when I have line-height, there is a space between internal lines. when line-height is normal - no space.. THANKS!

Comment: Just out of curiousity: do you work with the Doctype HTML STRICT declaration, or Transitional ? That might cause your problem as well. If you use Strict, you're pretty sure your layout will be shown the same in the most common browsers.

Comment: Actually using transitional but even when changing to strict - same issue

Answer (score 25):

This is a simple solution...

by adding a `<br/><br/>` in your `<li>` will add a blank line break directly underneath

```
<ul>
    <li>Line 1<br/><br/></li>
    <li>Line 2</li>
    <li>Line 3</li>
    <li>Line 4<br/><br/></li>
    <li>Line 5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Personally, since I'm using strict HTML I prefer strict HTML solutions... this is a good one :P

Answer (score 8):

For future people who end up on this question like me:
adding `white-space: pre-wrap;` to the `<ul>` worked for me! It also works with `\n` as an added bonus :)

```
ul {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

As a side note for Wordpress, `&nbsp;` and `<br />` will be automatically removed if present before the closing `</li>`.

In a hacky way, you can use a zero-width non-joiner (`&zwnj;`) or an invisible separator (`&#8291;`).

In text mode, do a carriage return and insert a `&zwnj;` before the closing `</li>`.

Example:

```
<ul>
  <li>List item with a blank line below
  &zwnj;</li>
  <li>List item</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  <dl>
<dt>Coffee</dt>
<dd>- black hot drink</dd>
<dt>Milk</dt>
<dd>- white cold drink</dd>
</dl>





  Coffee
    - black hot drink
  Milk
    - white cold drink
```

hope This may Help..

Comment: i have use dl,dt and dd..hope this is wht you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
<ul>
    <li>First Line</br>First Second Line</li>
    <li>Second Line</li>
</ul>
```

[Check This](http://jsfiddle.net/76pZX/)

Answer (score 1):

An improvement on [Rudrik's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5140658/2911458):

```
<UL>
   <LI>First Line
      <DD>Second Line</DD> <!-- No Space -->
   </LI>
   <LI>Third Line</LI>
   <LI>Fourth Line</LI>
</UL>
```

Word!

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
li{
    float: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a paragraph with the line break:

```
<li>
  <p>...</br></p>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try playing around with "line-height".

Answer (score 0):

Might this work for you?

```
<ul>
    <li><div>First line</div> second line</li>
    <li>Second li</li>
    <li>third li</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using inline CSS, create a division with a fixed height, but no content, to create an empty line between list items, just like using nested lists. If you don't know much about CSS, just copy this solution and edit the height (in pixels) to change the empty line height. Place an empty line with this code anywhere in the lists, and set whatever height you desire for each empty line created.:

```
<ul>
    <li>Line 1</li>
    <li>Line 2</li>
    <li>Line 3</li>
    <li>Line 4
       <div style="height: 10px;">
       </div>
    </li>
    <li>Line 5</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

/* CSS */

```
#keyskills:after {
content:"I.T. – data analytical, planning, design and interaction skills \A Data logging and reporting - averaging about 60 WPM \A Research skills, able to provide intermediate I.T. support ";
white-space: pre;

}
```

/* Body of HTML */

```
<p id="keyskills">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using flex as well as flex-direction. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would be helpfull

```
ul {
  list-style-position: outside;
}
```